# Connecting Android Studio Application with mysql server locally (Genymotion emulator)

Tags: php, android, mysql, database-connection

I am trying to connect my android application with mysql database through php script. I have tried everything and nothing goes well. So can you please tell me why am I getting this errors and how can I fix it. I want just to display the query on the screen, so I can be sure that I am connected and to go on with the coding.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String category;
    String JSON_String;
    String json_string;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new BackgroundTask().execute();
    }
    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        String json_url;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            json_url="http://10.0.2.3/webappdb/get_all_rows.php";//Script
            //super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((JSON_String = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){

                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_String + "\n");

                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
            textView.setText(result);
            json_string=result;



        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR LIST**

```
04-01 07:40:12.580 26083-26083/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
    04-01 07:40:12.600 26083-26089/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
    04-01 07:40:12.600 26083-26089/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    04-01 07:40:12.692 26083-26083/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
    04-01 07:40:12.692 26083-26083/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
    04-01 07:40:12.692 26083-26083/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15039: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
    04-01 07:40:12.692 26083-26083/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    04-01 07:40:12.692 26083-26083/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
    04-01 07:40:12.692 26083-26083/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15043: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    04-01 07:40:12.692 26083-26083/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    04-01 07:40:12.748 26083-26083/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    04-01 07:40:12.748 26083-26083/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 396: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    04-01 07:40:12.748 26083-26083/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    04-01 07:40:12.748 26083-26083/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    04-01 07:40:12.748 26083-26083/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 418: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    04-01 07:40:12.748 26083-26083/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    04-01 07:40:12.828 26083-26087/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 180K, 15% free 2674K/3132K, paused 26ms+1ms, total 29ms
    04-01 07:40:12.996 26083-26083/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
    04-01 07:40:13.008 26083-26083/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
    04-01 07:40:13.008 26083-26083/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
    04-01 07:40:13.076 26083-26083/? W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    04-01 07:40:13.084 26083-26083/? E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
    04-01 07:40:13.100 26083-26083/? E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
```

[Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE7ak.jpg)

Comment: try killing the 'adb' process and restart it.

Comment: Tried, but it is not helping. The problem is that I can't get the information from the database idk why...

Comment: Is your database located on the same machine you are developing on?
IDK the version of Genymotion emulator you are using, but that IP address in your API URL looks suspicious, try `10.0.3.2` if you are on 2.2 or higher.

if that still fails, try fetching data using other tools to be sure it exists, e.g. using Postman (chrome extension)

Comment: Yes, my database is located in the same machine, I am using wamp server as a localhost. I have Genymotion 2.6 and still, with 10.0.3.2 it is not working :/